# Is there some method to check if class is inherited from generic type?

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, swift3

Is there some method/procedure how to check if class is inherited from generic type without specifying exact generic type in swift?

Here is an example:

```
class AClass {
}

class BClass<T: UIView>: AClass {
    var a:T?
}

let myClass: AClass = BClass<UIImageView>()

myClass is BClass // false!
myClass is BClass<UIView> // false!
myClass is BClass<UIImageView> // true
```

I would like just to check if myClass is type of `BClass` and get access to `a` property (not just check mirror type).

```
Mirror(reflecting: myClass).subjectType //BClass<UIImageView>.Type
```

Comment: Doesn't `Swift` creates completely independent instance class for each generic parameter during compilation, without storing info considering relation of those instances?

Answer (score 0):

You could efine a protocol (e.g. BClassType), make your generic type use the protocol. You can then use myObject is BClassType to check if an instance is defined using your generic type.